# Wordpress menu in drop down?

Tags: html, wordpress, menu

I have a code in wordpress which generates a horizontal menu. The code is

```
<? php wp_nav_menu (array ('theme_location' => 'header-menu'));?>
```

I would like to have a drop down instead, and tried the following code but its not working.

```
<select name="blog-dropdown" onChange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
<option value="">Navigering</option><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?></select>
```

What is wrong? I get an empty drop down list.

Comment: I have tried differet values. I have forgot <option> as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to meet the similar requirement by using this WordPress function `wp_dropdown_pages($args);`

the drop down options contain the page id as value so i used them to redirect user through jquery. my jquery code looks as follows:

```
$("nav select").change(function() {
    var pageID  = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    window.location = siteurl + '?p=' + pageID;
});
```

here siteurl contains my home page URL(which is WordPress blog URL)
u can keep some div like below in the footer.php

```
<div id="wordpress_blog_url" style="display:none;"><?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?></div>
```

and then

```
var siteurl = $('#WordPress').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's empty in your browser but inspect the code (or read the html source).
The `wp_nav_menu` function create an `ul>li>a` tags.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu.

The option tag needs something like this :

```
<select>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```